# node.js server port not working

Tags: node.js, centos

So I am creating a simple server test on my Centos 5.x box and I am having troubles getting node.js to respond on my port:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

This is the standard copy/pasta test. I had it working last night, and it has since stopped working. I am running this out of /home/user/nodejs and do not get any compilation errors. There are no other node processes running either. Any ideas as to what could have happened between then and now? Any known  quirky nodejs problems that may be associated with this?

**edits:**

- I have tested various ports
- The page simply times out

**RHEL / Centos 5.8 / node v0.6.15**

Comment: already tried different ports?

Comment: no errors thrown by node.js when server is starting up? or when a request occurs? whats the behavior in the browser (timeout, reset, etc)?

Comment: What does "not working" mean in this particular case? Are you running SELinux or AppArmor, or something similar?

Comment: have you killed the nodejs processes?

Comment: @GonçaloVieira I did a `ps aux | grep node` and did not see any running

Comment: well from past experience this happened in ubuntu cuz I wasn't killing the process prior to re-testing. since the port was being used it didn't work (node wasn't even returning an error or anything), on that thought, try and check to see if the port is in use by another process. (PS, I know you tried other ports, but still there's a chance they were taken by something else.)

Comment: Looks like I got lucy before in choosing my port. I opened 8888 through WHM and got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to close the firewall?

Comment: Or open the specific system port which you're using.

Comment: Seems like it was a fluke before in choosing the ports. Specifically opening 8888 worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the firewall and it is working.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.